# What exactly is a template engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have done some googling and I understand that the template engine of Ruby is erb but what does a template engine mean?

Comment: Implementation-wise, Rails switched its `.erb` handler from [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) to [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) to [erubi](https://github.com/jeremyevans/erubi). All of these are compatible with ERB's `<% ... %>` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template engine are nothing but presentation layer, that represent actual logic/variable of rails application in html format. So end user can get what they are looking for.

Consider if you have `@users` object and you want to loop through each record and represent name of each user detail on webpage. There is no way in simple html to do so. So erb and other template engines comes in picture.

These engines covert/evaluate values of variables, functions and user defined syntax to html format and represent to end user.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

> Template is a pattern, mold, or the like, usually consisting of a thin plate of wood or metal, serving as a gauge or guide in mechanical work that determines or serves as a pattern; a model:
>   - **Dictionary Definition**

In our world of Programming, The template is a framework of any repetitive work sharing a common pattern. We extract out the common pattern as a template, now you can embed the changing/dynamic data and create your copy of the work.

**Example**: You notice forms you get in hospitals or Govt. offices where there are blank-fields for you to write your dynamic data. At last, you get your copy of the application. Don't you?

To facilitate this we have `ERB` as an engine in the standard library of `Ruby`.

Let's get our hand dirty; Try this and see results:

```
require 'erb'

your_template = <<-TEMP
  This document is a template for <%= title %> <%= full_name %>.

  Now we are going to have a line written <%= n %> times.

  <% n.times do %>
    This line must repeat <%= n %> times.
  <% end %>

TEMP

title = 'Mr.'
full_name = 'Shiva Gaire'
n = 5

generated_doc = ERB.new(your_template).result

puts generated_doc
```

**Output**

```
This document is a template for Mr. Shiva Gaire.

Now we are going to have a line written 5 times.

 This line must repeat 5 times.


 This line must repeat 5 times.


 This line must repeat 5 times.


 This line must repeat 5 times.


 This line must repeat 5 times.
```

Comment: nice and elegant